# Umlauts (Ö, Ü, Ä) on English US-International keyboards on Android with a physcial keyboard

Tags: keyboard

Alt codes don't seem to do anything.
AltGr + O, U, A create ó, ú, á.

I need a way to type ö, ü and ä without switching layouts.
I'm using a Galaxy Tab S7 on Android 11, if it matters.

Comment: Try to type " followed by A/O/U. That works on a International Keyboard Layout.

Comment: @Seth pretty sure that won't work on Android.

Answer (score 1):

The "international" version for US keyboards is

- `AltGr+q`-> ä
- `AltGr+y`-> ü
- `AltGr+p`-> ö

But whether this actually works might depend on how your physical keyboard is configured, as well as on your Android configuration.

Here's an image (source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_and_American_keyboards)) of the international layout:

[image]